# Override CSS Wildcard for half of page

Tags: html, css

I am running into this issue where the theme I'm trying to integrate has a CSS wildcard selector that is applied to the entire site. The problem is it breaks my previous form elements.

Please see this image for reference of the problem:
Bad:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGAUG.png

This is what I would like it to look like:
Good:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/584G6.png

To achieve the good look, I change the 'box-sizing' to content-box. The problem is the wildcard is continuously being applied to the entire page so it supersedes it, I believe.

Question #1: Can someone please show me how to apply this content-box to ONLY those two boxes on only one page?

Question #2: Kind of on point 1 - but this must only apply to those two boxes as the header and the entire rest of the site rely on that box-sizing: border-box

HERE IS A LIVE EXAMPLE:
failed
Problematic section, I think...

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Please take a gander at the live example and let me know exactly what to change to fix this issue. You can see all the things I've tried in there and none have worked yet. You will have my eternal gratitude and my blade in battle if you can help solve this.

Comment: just checked the class `.CollapsiblePanelTab`  `Background img` width is `660px` and you've define a width is `647px`. this is the reason.

Comment: your pen isn't loading for me, but just wondering: why don't you simply add your current  *, *:before[...] code at the beginning of CSS and then simply override the elements you need with content-box, just as you mention? I don't know if you were expecting something else, but that's EXACTLY the way to do it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Fabio codepen is not working bcz OP have add <html> tag and `Doctype ` also.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Edit: That fixed it thank you my friend, you sir, are a god amongst men!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look the class `.CollapsiblePanelTab` Where Background img `width` is `660px` and you've define the `width:647px`. Make sure the width is eqaul to background image width.

**Here is the CSS code**

```
.CollapsiblePanelTab {
    font: normal 21px Arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 0px #CCC;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    width: 660px; /*change it from 647 to 660px*/
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/6wGRmmk.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000000;
}
```

> **Side Note:** you are using `-khtml-user-select: none;` thats  were used for very older version. To target the latest version of chrome and safari you must use `-webkit` prefix.
>   Read More at **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)**.

Comment: Welcome MY Friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
        .pnl_1
        {
            width :60%;
            height :50px;
             border : 1px solid blue;
             border-radius :5px;
         }
</style>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_id" runat="server" CssClass ="pnl_1" >
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
```